# How to set model instance variable in Rspec rails

Tags: rspec

I have a rails model where I have defined my method and assigned instance variable.

```
def add_token_details
  @token = {name: "random", type: "outside"}
end
```

In rspec model, how can i set this @token inside my test method??
I tried

```
assigns(:token) = {name: "random", type: "outside"}
```

But it didn't work. Inside my test example I need to access @token value.

Comment: assigns is an rspec controller method feature. Instance variables are generally considered implementation details that tests should not touch directly. An allowance is made for controllers, since ivars are used to pass data to views, and thus become more than internal controller state. The accessor approach is the correct way to fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off to make `@token` an `attr_reader` and then stub it, via:

```
allow(my_obj).to receive(:token).and_return({name: "random", type: "outside"})
```

Note:  that stub has to go at the top of your test.